# Launching SQL procedure error

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not familiar with SQL but have to do little thing.
I have following procedure in SQL:

```
create or replace procedure utworz_tabele (rozmiar_pol in number)
as 
begin 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE osoby(
id_osoby NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
imie varchar2 (' || rozmiar_pol || '),
nazwisko varchar2 (' || rozmiar_pol || '))';
end;
```

I'm trying to execute it with:

```
begin 
utworz_tabele(50);
end;
```

But that throws an error:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
>   begin
>   utworz_tabele(50);
>   end;
>
> Error report -
>   ORA-00907: brak prawego nawiasu
>   ORA-06512: przy "MIF16CF11.UTWORZ_TABELE", linia 4
>   ORA-06512: przy linia 2
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Oracle errors come from Oracle, not SQL Server.

Comment: Remove the space between the varchar2 and open parentesis `varchar2(` and also add a `;` at the end of the statement `....|| '));'` and try it again

Comment: I can execute the procedure w/o any issues. What is your client?